# Short Vs Int Gcc

Tags: c, time, int, short

I was expecting Loop2 in the following program to take more time compared to Loop1.
But even after enabling optimizations (gcc -O2) I see that both of the loops takes almost same time. Why is that so in my system with sizeof(int)=4 and sizeof(short)=2 ? I was expecting compiler to put a short multiply instruction for multiplying shorts and hence shorter time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

float DiffTime(struct timespec Start,struct timespec Stop);

main ()
{
    struct timespec start,stop;    
    int    i;  
    short  a,b,c;
    int    p,q,r;

    a=1;
    b=2;
    c=3;
    p=1;
    q=2;
    r=3;
    clock_gettime (CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &start);
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++) // Loop1
    {
        a=b*a;
    }
    clock_gettime (CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &stop);
    printf("Time taken %11.9fs\n",DiffTime(start,stop));
    clock_gettime (CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &start);
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++) // Loop2
    {
        p=q*p;
    }
    clock_gettime (CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &stop);
    printf("Time taken %11.9fs\n",DiffTime(start,stop));

    printf("%d,%d\n",a,p);        

}

float DiffTime(struct timespec Start,struct timespec Stop)    
{
 long nTime1,nTime2;
 nTime1=Start.tv_sec*1000000000 + Start.tv_nsec ;
 nTime2=Stop.tv_sec*1000000000 + Stop.tv_nsec ;
 return((float)(nTime2-nTime1)/1000000000);
}
```

Comment: The word "short" in "short multiplication" doesn't refer to the execution time of the operation...

Comment: Can you explain why you expected `short`s to be faster?

Comment: why do you think a 4 byte `imul` will take longer than a 2 byte one on a modern procesor?

Comment: Like many said there is no 16bit multiply instruction for x86. But why ? Now it becomes a comp-arch question. Assuming a sequential multiplier a 16bit multiplication could be performed faster. Any clues why they didn't implemented 16bit multiplication ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't expect to be able to second-guess your compiler when it comes to performance. About the only thing you should expect are better big-O times based on your algorithms.

If the manual says that the size of a data type is X, that's all it's claiming and that's all you should expect.

Comment: "Don't expect to be able to second-guess your compiler" - and that's how you got my upvote.

Comment: There are plenty of cases where the compiler isn't good enough. From what I've experienced, compilers can get up to 80-90% of total performance right. Whatever is left is up to the programmer. I'm talking algorithm optimization, not selection

Comment: @gl3829: I'll take your word for it; I don't peek under the hood because I know the compiler does a better job than I can do and I think this is a waste of time.  If my code is too slow, I look at the algorithm. If I try a peephole optimization, I do so knowing I'm rolling the die, and I don't worry if it doesn't work, it was a shot in the dark to begin with. I also know the risks involved -- like implementation changes invalidating the optimization.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be suprised if both loops are empty after enabling optimizations.  Did you trying increasing N by a factor of 10 and seeing if there were differences?

Comment: Even when I am consuming the output using a printf ?

Comment: A simple optimizer could recognize that nothing changes within the loop and only execute the multiply once.   A smart optimizer could recognize that nothing changes at all, and set `a` and `p` to 6 at compile time.

Comment: Yes it does..It is recursive multiplication.

Comment: oops, I read it as `a=b*c`.  Still, the printf output is constant, and subject to optimization.  It goes back to @RonaldBarzell's comment: You can't really predict what the optimizer will generate, just that it will produce the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

On most 32-bit architectures -- x86 included -- multiplying 16-bit values takes the same time as 32-bit values. (Indeed, it will likely be using the exact same instruction.)

Answer (score 0):

On most hardware platforms there will be only one type of integer execution unit and it will execute integer operations independent of size in the same amount of CPU cycles. So multiplying `signed char`, `short`, `int`, `long long int` will take the same time because it's the same piece of hardware that does it.

Answer (score 0):

As people already said, the processors ALU have a fixed size and will promote smaller ints to that preferred size. Modern processors have at least 32bit ALUs. 
A point no-one mentioned yet, is that on 32 or 64 bit machines, it can even happen that using shorter types will generate slower code. Because of some esoteric rules, the code generator may need to add explicit sign extension instructions in certain cases. I had that effect on Solaris on SPARC with gcc v3, which added boatloads of 16bit truncation instructions to the code, making shorts measurably slower than using int.